# Apache DBCP and Oracle Transparent Application continuity

Tags: java, oracle, apache-commons-dbcp

We have an older application that can't failover when one node of our Oracle RAC goes down.  It seems it uses an older version of org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.  I can make this work when I use UCP from Oracle but when I use the apache version the app dies as soon as I shut down the node of the RAC it is connected to. Am I missing something or does it not work with Apache DBCP?  Thanks

Here is my code.

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class BasicDB{



    final static String DB_URL ="jdbc:oracle:thin:user/password@pdb_tac";
    final static String driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl";

    private void pressAnyKeyToContinue()
    {
        System.out.print("Press any key to continue...");
        try { System.in.read(); }
        catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
    public String getInstanceName(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select instance_name from v$instance");
        String r = new String();

        for(ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery(); result.next(); r = result.getString("instance_name")) {
        }

        pstmt.close();
        return r;
    }



    private void doTx(Connection c, int numValue) throws SQLException {
        String updsql = "UPDATE test SET v=UPPER(v) WHERE id=?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        pstmt = c.prepareStatement(updsql);
        c.setAutoCommit(false);

        for(int i = 0; i < numValue; ++i) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, i);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }

        c.commit();
        pstmt.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        int numValue = 5000;
;

        try {

            BasicDataSource bods = new BasicDataSource();
            bods.setUrl(DB_URL);
            bods.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
            bods.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
            BasicDB self = new BasicDB();
            conn = bods.getConnection();
            String var10001 = self.getInstanceName(conn);
            var10000.println("Instance Name = " + var10001);
            System.out.println("Performing transactions");
            self.pressAnyKeyToContinue();
            self.doTx(conn, numValue);
            var10001 = self.getInstanceName(conn);
            var10000.println("Instance Name = " + var10001);

        } catch (Exception var8) {
            var8.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the error I get when I attempt to run this code. BasicDB - SQLException occurred : Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl' for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@pdb_tac'

Comment: It seems I am using a Datasource where the DataDriver class name is.  Also the Basic Data Source won't accomplish what I am trying to accomplish.  Will need to look in DataSource and poolable connection factories.  Will post more once I nail this down.

Comment: Ok, so here is where I am now.  It seems I can get past the Cannot create JDBC driver class error but now I have run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it has to do with using the DataSource instead of the DataDriver class.  I have run into another error so will create a new question for that.